# How to interpret this output in Dimension Reduction?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

I'm running Linear Discriminant Analysis on a dataset and then performing clustering on it. I'm reducing it to dimensions 2,6,10. On comparing metrics like Accuracy and Normalized Mutual Information, the values at dimension 6 reduce by almost half. While at dimension 10 it is close to dimension 2. I'm not able to comprehend why the accuracy might go down and then up again.

The point is why do we see for 2D and 10D a better answer and for 6D a worse answer. I mean u go from 2D to 6D, the accuracy goes worse and then goes back up again for 10D

Comment: Do I get you right?: You perform LDA on k classes in p-dim space and leave m dimensions (discriminants); you then do cluster analysis in these m dimensions whereby partition data into k clusters. Then you compare how much initial classes and the emergent clusters coincide.

Comment: Yup, is something wrong with this approach?

Comment: Well, most generally it is warranted. But why don't you do clustering of initial data first, to compare p-dim clusters with m-dim clusters (not predefined classes with clusters)? What is your aim, after all? I miss it.

Comment: I'm comparing approaches and trying what works best when. I'm doing what you are saying too.

Comment: Are you dividing the data set into training and test data sets? I'm not sure if that could do this.

Comment: Forgive me for being so fuzzy, but you're saying that you're reducing your data to 2-D, 6-D, and 10-D and clustering in those spaces, respectively, and you're puzzled as to why clustering in a higher-dimensional space might not be more accurate than in a lower-dimensional space? My naive answer would be either: a) it's an overfitting kind of issue, or b) the input features are of widely different scales.

Comment: The point is why do we see for 2D and 10D a better answer and for 6D a worse answer. I mean u go from 2D to 6D, the accuracy goes worse and then goes back up again for 10D

Comment: Oops, I had it backwards: I'd misread that accuracy went up and then back down. Maybe your results are an artifact of using a linear method on relationships that turn out to be highly non-linear?

Comment: Wayne can you elaborate more on that?